# Generation of types in zig

Tags: zig

Is it possible to create a `comptime` function in zig that would generate a new struct type? The function would receive an array of strings and an array of types. The strings are the names of subsequent struct fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially. This has been long proposed at https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/383

You can only do so with `fields`, not with custom `decls`.

Comment: Thanks. I was guessing it was not possible (or else the doc would brag about it).

Answer (score 19):

This has been implemented now as https://github.com/ziglang/zig/pull/6099

```rust
const builtin = @import("std").builtin;
const A = @Type(.{
    .Struct = .{
        .layout = .Auto,
        .fields = &[_]builtin.TypeInfo.StructField{
            .{ .name = "one", .field_type = i32, .default_value = null, .is_comptime = false, .alignment = 0 },
        },
        .decls = &[_]builtin.TypeInfo.Declaration{},
        .is_tuple = false,
    },
});
test "" {
    const a: A = .{ .one = 25 };
}
```

The TypeInfo struct is defined [here](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/builtin.zig#L183).